# How to set a Spring Cloud Eureka app's zone

Tags: spring-cloud

This is probably a dumb question ;-).

In Spring's ribbon code (ZonePreferenceServerListFilter), I see:

```
    if (ConfigurationManager.getDeploymentContext() != null) {
        this.zone = ConfigurationManager.getDeploymentContext().getValue(
                ContextKey.zone);
    }
```

The zone name defaults to 'defaultZone'.

How/where can I set that value for my application?

I tried setting eureka.instance.metadataMap.zone in application.yml but that did not work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Henry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is `eureka.client.availabilityZones` which is a list. Then you can set `eureka.client.serviceUrl.<yourzone>=<eurekaurlforthatzone`.

Comment: Adding "eureka.client.availabilityZones.default: myzone" worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple zones, you may find some more details here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/991

With the enhancement provided there you **can** set the zone of the Eureka-Ribbon-Client with `eureka.instance.metadataMap.zone`. If you use earlier versions of Spring Cloud you can still use the property `"@zone"` in your application.yaml.

The approach to use `availabilityZones` to set the zone is limited to setups with only one zone, since the first one will be always used.